# How to prove that $(\Bbb{Z}[t]+t\Bbb{R}[t])/t\Bbb{R}[t]\cong\Bbb{Z}\cong\Bbb{Z}[t]/t\Bbb{Z}[t]\cong\Bbb{Z}[t]/(\Bbb{Z}[t]\cap t\Bbb{R}[t])$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism, polynomial-rings, ring-isomorphism

I already proved that $(\mathbb{Z}[t]+t\mathbb{R}[t])/t\mathbb{R}[t]\cong\mathbb{Z}[t]/(\mathbb{Z}[t]\cap t\mathbb{R}[t])$ with the first isomorphism theorem but i do not know how to continue.

Comment: 3rd one is $\mathbb{Z}[t]/t\mathbb{Z}[t]$, right?

Comment: yes that was a typing error

Comment: I believe you want to use the first isomorphism theorem to prove all three are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. The isomorphism is actually the same for all three. Send a polynomial $p(t) = a_0 + a_1t+ \cdots + a_nt^n$ to its constant term $a_0$. This is a ring homomorphism because it's just evaluating the polynomial at $p(0)$. Show that in each case the image is all of $\mathbb{Z}$ and that the kernel is the set you want.

Comment: Let $\psi: \mathbb{Z}[t]\longmapsto\mathbb{Z}, p(t)\longmapsto p(0)$ be a ring homomorphism. Then the kernel is $t\mathbb{Z}[t]$ and the image is $\mathbb{Z}$. $\Longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\cong(\mathbb{Z}[t]/t\mathbb{Z}[t])$ Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equality $\mathbb{Z}[t]\cap t\mathbb{Z}[t]=t\mathbb{Z}[t]$ is clear (if you're not convinced, take 30sec to prove it), so the last isomorphism is in fact an equality.

It remains to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[t]/t\mathbb{Z}[t]\simeq\mathbb{Z}$, which can be achieved by applying the first isomorphism theorem to evaluation at $0$.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}[t]\cap t\mathbb{R}[t]=t\mathbb{Z}[t]$ because the last isomorphism is: $\mathbb{Z}[t]/t\mathbb{Z}[t]\cong\mathbb{Z}[t]/(\mathbb{Z}[t]\cap t\mathbb{R}[t])$

Comment: yes, it was a typo. Corrected now.

Comment: there is still a typing error